# How to save compute results in Models without re-computing to each call?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Actually, I got a model, with theses functions:

```
def speed_score(self):
  high_intensity_running_time = ((self.h_i_run_time * 100/self.training_length) * 8)
  if self.h_i_average_speed < 15:
    average_speed_score = 10
  else:
    average_speed_score = self.cross_multiplication(30, self.h_i_average_speed, 50)
  final_speed_score = int(high_intensity_running_time + average_speed_score)
  if final_speed_score < 0 or final_speed_score > 100:
  final_speed_score = 0
  return final_speed_score

def stamina_score(self):
  if self.distance < 1000:
    distance_score = 5
  else:
    distance_score = self.cross_multiplication(16, (self.distance / 1000), 40)
  high_intensity_running_duration = self.cross_multiplication(500, self.h_i_run_time, 30)
  print self.pace
  if self.pace < 0.10:
    pace_score = 5
  else:
    pace_score = self.cross_multiplication(0.36, self.pace, 30)
  print pace_score
  final_stamina_score = int(distance_score + high_intensity_running_duration + pace_score)
  if final_stamina_score < 0 or final_stamina_score > 100:
    final_stamina_score = 0
  return final_stamina_score

def activity_score(self):
  if self.running_time_ratio <= 0.10:
    running_time_ratio_score = 10
  else:
    running_time_ratio_score = self.cross_multiplication(50, self.running_time_ratio, 50)
  run_per_min = self.run_number / (self.training_length/60)
  if run_per_min < 1:
    run_number_ratio = 5
  else:
    run_number_ratio = self.cross_multiplication(5, run_per_min, 50)
  final_activity_score = int(running_time_ratio_score + run_number_ratio)
  if final_activity_score < 0 or final_activity_score > 100:
    final_activity_score = 0
  return final_activity_score
```

As you can see theses are very basics functions to compute score on a game. I call them in my serializer as following:

```
class SessionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  owner = NestedOwnerSerializer()

  class Meta:
    model = FieldPlayer
    fields = ['id', 'date', 'owner', 'report_id', 'speed_score', 'stamina_score', 'activity_score']
```

But the fact is that every time I call theses functions, it run them and make them computing. This is not the behaviour that I need, because computing have to be done only in the first call.

I would like to store them in a models.IntegerField.

How can I properly do this ? I didn't found any example of this kind of usage in DRF's doc.

Comment: Don't make us do the leg-work.  Put the relevant code in your question.

Comment: There is no "relevant code". I'm asking on how can I store permanently functions result in a Model.

Comment: If the code isn't relevant, why is the link in your question?

Comment: If you would've taken two minutes to read my pastebin and my post with attention you would have noticed that I posted this to show you all the "*_score" functions that I want to do only one time, instead of re-computing each time that i'm using this model.

Comment: Put the code **here**, not in a pastebin.

Comment: Compute them in your model's save() method, then store the results into fields.

Comment: I'm totally new to Django and python in general. Do you have an exemple to illustrate this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm totally new to Django and python in general. Do you have an exemple to illustrate this?

### Let's start with saving these in a DB

I don't know where you want to store the scores, but let's assume it's in `FieldPlayer`

```
class FieldPlayer(models.Model):

    speed_score = models.IntegerField() # or FloatField() etc
    another_score = ...

    def save_scores(self):
        self.speed_score = calculate_speed_score(...)
        self.another_score = calculate_another_score(...)

        self.save()
```

Now everything the score changes, your game logic needs to save those, by calling `FieldPlayer.save_scores()`

### Use those fields in the serializer

Then, in the serializer, instead of *calculating* those fields, you simply read them again from the database, like the other regular fields.

### Cache the scores in memory for more performance

To improve performance, it is possible, after reading those values from the DB, to store them in a cache. Just remember to update the cache when the score is updated (e.g. when you call `PlayerField.save_scores()`)

That way you don't hit the database with every request. The database is hit only to update the score and read it once until it is changed again.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I want. But I don't see where I have to call `FieldPlayer.save_scores()`, must be something evident that I don't get ?

Comment: You need to call it after every and any operation in the game logic that is susceptible to change the score of a player. E.g. in a turn based game that would be after each turn is completed. Depends on the game, the important thing is to update the score in the DB when something happens in the game and you want the score updated.

Comment: In fact, FieldPlayer represent a sport session. Score are calculated only one time and will never changes.